# SWT Chromium browser subprocesses continue running after application is closed

Tags: java, subprocess, swt, chromium, chromium-embedded

I've updated to SWT 4.17.0 recently which allows the use of `SWT.CHROMIUM` as a `style` value on a `Browser`. When creating the `Browser` a `chromium_subp-4936r26.exe` process is created in Task Manager in Windows.

Sometimes when closing the application, the subprocess is removed from Task Manager, but other times, it will just stick around and actually start to use more and more CPU to the point where fans in the laptop start to go into high gear.

I've tried adding a `DisposeListener` on the parent `Composite` to call `browser.close();` and `browser.dispose();` but that doesn't always work.

I've also gone so far as to outright call `Chromium.shutdown();` while my application closes and it still isn't consistent. It looks like there are some examples of subprocesses continuing to run ( https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?t=15413 ) but with the way Chromium is implemented in SWT, I don't think I have access to those inner objects.

I've tested out if it happens if I'm leaving the window open for a long time or if it's only happening when opening the window and closing before it fully creates the `Browser`. It might leave the subprocess going more often when I close it quickly, but I can't guarantee that's an accurate assessment.

What, if anything, can I do to be sure that all `chromium_subp-4936r26.exe` processes are killed when my application closes?

Comment: It might be better to ask this on [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) where the developers should see it